# Plotting step and impulse responses on Matlab

Tags: matlab, step-response

I'm trying to graph a simple response function:
`1/(1-0.5s^-1)`

Now, I know that the function can also be written as: `s/(s-0.5)`

So I tried plotting the step and impulse responses in Matlab:

```
sys = tf([1 0],[1 -0.5])
figure(1);
step(sys);
figure(2);
impulse(sys);
```

And these are the graphs that I'm getting:
[image: Graph of step and impulse responses]

I think the shape of the step response is right; however, shouldn't the impulse response decay?

It just doesn't seem right that both graphs have the same shape.

Comment: I think Mathematics would be a better community to ask this on.

Answer (score 3):

Your system is unstable - the pole is in the right half s-plane.

Look at the vertical scales: \$10^{25}\$

If you want to get the step and impulse responses of an arbitrary, but stable, system try: \$sys=\small tf([1], [1\hspace{2mm} 1])\$

Answer (score 1):

The system is unstable, the pole is in the rigth-half plane, then, the response increases exponentially.

Maybe you can try whit rlocus() function, to get another graphic representation.